# JavaScript - DOM Manipulation - Is construction a page first then attaching?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

New to javascript...and dom manipulation...Let's say I'm using java-script to construct part of a page that has a bunch of sub-elements.

```
<div>my-sub-elements</div>
```

Should I create a stand-alone-div attach the elements inside then attach the whole thing to the DOM?

Or should I attach the elements one by one to the DOM?

Comment: you should create standalone then attach all at once, whether in a frag or elm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually will not be able to notice a difference, but in case you really need it then constructing a detached [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and attaching it in a single step is faster than messing with the live DOM tree many times.

Comment: thanks I'm going to be spiking this using angular...and your reference to DocumentFrament, led me to this article: http://andrewmerrell.co.uk/angularjs-with-900-dom-elements/